# serial number add not synchronized

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety, threadpool

I don't know after put everywhere I can imagine "synchronized",but it's still thread not safe,help,thanks a lot!Multithread contend to add a serial number 'a'.should the thread Demo's run method can be synchronized? Anyway,I add it to the "public void run()" a synchronized,it still display an unsafe message.

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class NumberEx {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ExecutorService service=Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
        for(int i=0;i<10;i++) {
            service.execute(new ThreadDemo());
        }
        service.shutdown();

    }
}


package stackoverflow;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;

public class ThreadDemo implements Runnable  {
    private static volatile int a = 0;
    private static volatile List<Integer> list=new ArrayList<Integer>();
    static PrintWriter writer;
    static {
        try {
            writer=new PrintWriter("./src/out.txt");
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run()  {

         while (a< 1000) {
                //critical section
                a= increment(a);
                //end
         }
            writer.close();

    }

    private static synchronized int increment(int a)  {

        writer.print("<<<<============"+Thread.currentThread().getName()+"========================     ");

        a=a+1;
        Integer temp=new Integer(a);

       writer.print(" Thread["+Thread.currentThread().getName()+"]" + ":"+ a);
       writer.print("      ============="+Thread.currentThread().getName()+"=======================>>>>>    "); 
        if(list.contains(temp)) {
            System.out.println("repeat number"+temp);
            Iterator<Integer> iter=list.iterator();
            while(iter.hasNext()) {
                System.out.print(iter.next()+" ");
            }
            System.exit(0);
        }else {
            list.add(temp);
        }
       writer.println(" "+temp+"\n");

        return a;
    } 

}
```

Comment: Unsurprisingly concurrent programming is more than "putting `synchronized` everywhere you can think of". What are you talking about "displays an unsafe message"?

Comment: @Kayaman, Unsurprising to you maybe, but based on the homework questions that continually pop up in this forum, it seems like there's a lot of teachers out there spreading bad information about mutexes (why and when and when not to use them), and about threads in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the stupid question,I recently learn about the object monitor,and finally resolve ti with synchronizing on the object

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but I think you need to surround

```
//critical section
a= increment(a);
 //end
```

with a synchronized block and introduce a lock object like this:

```
private static final Object LOCK = new Object();

@Override
public void run() {

    while (true) {
        synchronized (LOCK) {
            if(a<1000){
                //critical section
                a = increment(a);
                //end
            }else{
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You need to check the condition inside of the synchronized block as well, otherwise you will get numbers higher than 1000.

Edit. previous answer was incorrect.

Comment: nope,'this' reference to current thread,it certainly not work!because synchronized lock the current thread,not the shared resource

Comment: with output,repeat at 227